# Aren't these questions correct?

Tags: prepositions

1. How long does it take from New York to Washington by plane?
2. How long does it take by plane from New York to Washington?

I mean, is the priority of prepositions important, is it necessary to use the preposition "by" first?

Comment: I don't think they are "wrong".  These would be understood and it really makes little difference where you insert "by plane" - both positions work just fine.  However, it might be better to say "How long does it take **to fly from** X to Y." - I feel this would be more natural/idiomatic.

Comment: They are not *clearly expressed* questions and if trying to clearly express something in writing, they might fall short.  However, they certainly qualify as idiomatic sentences that a speaker would use in context.  If you and I are discussing travel times, I might even reduce the sentence to, *How long from New York to Washington by plane?*

Answer (score 9):

Both questions are understandable and a native speaker would likely know exactly what was meant, but I’m not sure either are grammatically correct because the actual getting/traveling (the verb) has been left out.

A clearer way to write each would be, “how long does it take to get from Washington to New York by plane?”

Or, “how long does it take to travel from W to NY by plane?”

Or - and this option has no “by” - “how long is the flight between W and NY?”

Comment: “how long is the flight between W and NY?” might be answered in time or distance. Suggest “What is the flight time between W and NY?”

Comment: @user20637 - No.  *How long is the flight,* always means how much time will the flight take.  It never means, *How far will you travel?*  If you want to know how many miles someone will travel you would ask that specifically, *How far away is that?* or *How far is your flight?* If you use the word **long** in reference to a flight, you mean **time**.  If you use the word **far**, you mean **distance**.

Comment: @EllieK - I can only support my opinion by my decades of experience as a UK English speaker. If your opinion has equally weak support I guess we'll have to agree to disagree,

Comment: @user20637 - Are you saying that if I asked you how long your flight to Hong Kong was, you might respond *4,260 kilometers*?  OK?  Maybe in a couple more decades it will make sense.

Comment: From courtesy I will reply - YES. However I suggest this conversation is unhelpful. I do not intend to respond further to unsupported comments.